# Obter valores do 4º nó do Firebase em Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

Preciso buscar os valores grifados em vermelho na imagem, mas eu apenas conheço o item grifado em azul.

[image: Nó no banco]

Tentei dessa maneira:

```
firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("tb_contato").child(identificador);
                valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot filho: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            Contato contato = filho.getValue(Contato.class);
                            Log.i("Teste","Teste");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Onde o "identificador" é o valor grifado em azul da imagem.

Mas ao tentar compilar, ele me retorna assim:
[image: Retorno]

Comment: Pelo que colocou na pergunta, seu banco parece estar mal estruturado, é melhor evitar ao máximo o aninhamento de dados. A única forma que vejo é fazer um loop nas chaves, guardar em um array e usar para acessar os dados filhos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi dessa maneira, não sei se é o mais adequado, mas funcionou.

```
firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("tb_contato").child(identificador);
                valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot filho: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                chaveServico = filho.getKey();
                                firebaseContato = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("tb_contato").child(identificador).child(chaveServico);
                                valueEventListenerContato = new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot filho: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                        {
                                            //===== Altera o nome do usuário no contato =======
                                            String chaveUsuario = filho.getKey();
                                            firebaseUsuario = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
                                            DatabaseReference hopperRef2 = firebaseUsuario.child("tb_contato").child(identificador).child(chaveServico).child(chaveUsuario);
                                            Map<String, Object> hopperUpdates2 = new HashMap<>();
                                            hopperUpdates2.put("cttUsrIDNomeSolicitante", txtNome.getText().toString());
                                            hopperRef2.updateChildren(hopperUpdates2);

                                            firebaseUsuario = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
                                            DatabaseReference hopperRef3 = firebaseUsuario.child("tb_contato").child(chaveUsuario).child(chaveServico).child(identificador);
                                            Map<String, Object> hopperUpdates3 = new HashMap<>();
                                            hopperUpdates3.put("cttUsrNomePrestador", txtNome.getText().toString());
                                            hopperRef3.updateChildren(hopperUpdates3);
                                            //=================================================
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                };
                                firebaseContato.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListenerContato);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```